# Jackson unmarshal: store inner xml as string

Tags: java, xml, jackson, unmarshalling

My XML:

```
<body>
   <type>authorizationStatus</type>
   <data>
      <AuthorizationStatusMessage>
         <id>12345679</id>
         <email>abc</email>
      </AuthorizationStatusMessage>
   </data>
</body>
```

I want to unmarshal this XML to a POJO like that:

```
public class XMPPMessage {
    private String type;
    private String data;
}
```

Jackson unmarshal gives me a HashMap:

```
{AuthorizationStatusMessage={id_colaborador=12345679, email=rhochman@atech.com}}
```

But I want keep the data inner XML as a String like that:

```
<AuthorizationStatusMessage><id>12345679</id><email>abc</email></AuthorizationStatusMessage>
```

How can I keep the inner XML as a String??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two options.

1. If you can modify your XML schema, you might want to leverage `CDATA` section (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) to keep your `<data>` contents as `String`.
2. You can implement a custom Jackson deserializer to extract `type` and `data` only. There are plenty of good references on the web (e.g. http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization).

Comment: I got it someway... I found a library named Conversion Box ( http://capsulesforthejavamind.blogspot.in/2015/01/conversion-box.html ) to convert HashMap to XML.

Answer (score 0):

I got it someway... I found a library named [Conversion Box](http://capsulesforthejavamind.blogspot.in/2015/01/conversion-box.html) to convert HashMap to XML.

Answer (score 0):

I create custom Deserializer for storing inner XML as String, example on Kotlin:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdScalarDeserializer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper


object XmlInnerDeserializer : StdScalarDeserializer<String>(String::class.java) {
    override fun deserialize(jp: JsonParser?, context: DeserializationContext?): String {
        val node = jp!!.codec.readTree<ObjectNode>(jp)
        val xmlMapper: ObjectMapper = XmlMapper()
        val xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(node)
        return xml.toString()
    }
}
```

How use it:

```java
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "body")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class XMPPMessage (
    @JsonDeserialize(using = XmlInnerDeserializer::class)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "data")
    val data: String
}
```

Field `data` contains `"<ObjectNode><AuthorizationStatusMessage>... </AuthorizationStatusMessage></ObjectNode>"` string.